# Is it possible to define all bitwise operators using a 'bitwise nand' similar to how all boolean logic can be built using just 'boolean nand'?

Tags: bitwise-operators, boolean

`Nand` is known as a 'universal' logic gate, because it allows you define all other boolean logic gates:

```
not(x) = nand(x,x)
and(x, y) = not(nand(x, y))
or(x, y) = nand(not(x), not(y))
nor(x, y) = not(or(x, y))
xor(x, y) = nand(nand(a, nand(a, b)), nand(b, nand(a, b)))
```

This is known as [nand-logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAND_logic), and is commonly used in modern computers because a transistor can be made to behave just like a nand-gate.

I am wondering if it is possible to do something similar with the bitwise operations. Can an e.g. *bitwise nand* (bnand) be used to define `bnot`, `bor`, `band`, `bnor`, `bxor`? Is there an universal bitwise operation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On a hardware level there is no difference between bitwise and logical. So, yes. A logical operation is just a bitwise operation on a single bit.

Answer (score 2):

On most modern microprocessors the bitwise operations are implemented natively, so that there is no benefit of having a NAND operation.

For example the x86 instruction set has: [AND](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/AND.html), [OR](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/OR.html), [XOR](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/XOR.html), [NOT](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/NOT.html). These all are performed in one single cycle as far as I know, so that there would be no benefit by replacing them with several NAND operations.  It also has [ANDN](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ANDN.html) which is an equivalent for `((NOT x) AND y)` that could be generated by a clever optimization compiler to gain a cycle.

The [RISC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_instruction_set_computing) movement tried to promote reduced instruction set for a simpler an more performant architecture. The idea was that compilers would have to combine simpler and faster instructions.   It appears however that [apart from](https://www.ece.umd.edu/~blj/RiSC/RiSC-isa.pdf) some experimental or teaching processors, most provide natively NAND as well as the usual bitwise operations (e.g. [PowerPC](http://www.ds.ewi.tudelft.nl/vakken/in1006/instruction-set/) or [ARM](http://www.heyrick.co.uk/assembler/qfinder.html)).

Comment: I am genuinely not sure how boolean operators are implemented in CPUs these days, but it used to be fairly common to use a 4-to-1 mux, feeding in "the truth table" as the 4 inputs, then use the two bits to operate on as the selector for the output. Gives you a single circuit that can be used for all 16 two-operand boolean functions.

Comment: The fact that OR, XOR and NOT are implemented "natively"and take no more than a single clock cycle says nothing about whether they are build using only NAND circuits or nor. I suspect they are build using only NANDs these days because transistors are really cheap and really fast. Vatine's 4-to-1 method is optimized for using a small number of transistors, which is pointless in the nanometer era.

Comment: RISC has been rendered meaningless by time. When it emerged, typical complex instructions took multiple clock cycles, like 10 or so. And this was not about OR/AND/NOT, these were already quick and considered "simple" and essential for any CPU so they would certainly not be dropped by a RISC processor. Today, complex instructions take less then a clock cycle (due to pipelining and multi-threading/multi-core.